# Addition of two decimal numbers in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I add two decimal numbers in `jquery` like `(1000+1500.25)`?
I tried like this :

```
amnt1=1000;
amnt2=1000;
```

I'm getting sum equal `2.00`

Comment: i need like this amnt1=1,000.00 and amnt2=1,000.00 and sum is 2,000.00

Comment: I am afraid you can not use Jquery to solve this. You will have to have Javascript's parseFloat function for the same e.g. var amnt1 = parseFloat(1000) ; var amnt2 = parseFloat(100); console.log(amnt1 + amnt2);

Comment: i already used parseFloat function

Comment: show us the updated code please

Comment: its okey,when we add float values.and also i need huge amount of additiopn like 1,50,512+55,65,215..Can you please help?

Comment: the values will be taken from db.

Comment: CreditSum = 0.00;$("td.credit").each(function(i,v){ m3 = $(v).text();  m4 = m3.replace(/\,/g,""); CreditSum = parseFloat(CreditSum) + parseFloat(m4)
  }); return CreditSum;

Comment: use parseLong and be happy :)

Comment: sorry,parseLong is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try parseFloat and toLocaleString:

```
var amnt1 = 1000;
var amnt2=1500.25;
var ans = parseFloat(amnt1)+parseFloat(amnt2);
alert(ans.toLocaleString())
var formatted_num = ans.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: i need answer like this amnt1=1000;amnt2=1500.25;and total=2,500.25

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Wnumb](http://refreshless.com/wnumb/). I'm pretty positive this is what you're looking for unless i got your question wrong.

So here if you put 1000 + 1000.25 it will give you "$ 2000.25 postfix".

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5z4nsmx/1/) for it (it works on input keyup). You can convert your number back and forth.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var moneyFormat = wNumb({
    mark: '.',
    thousand: ',',
    prefix: '$ ',
    postfix: ' postfix'
  });


$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    var finp =$('#finp').val();
    var sinp =$('#sinp').val();
    var total = parseFloat(finp) + parseFloat(sinp)
    $('.result').html(moneyFormat.to(total));
    });
});


<input type='number' value="0" id="finp"/>
<input type='number' value="0" id="sinp"/>
<span class='result'></span>
```